# Json to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
arr= [{'comment': u'NoComment',
  'creator': u'',
  'short': u'WQhBxVA',
  'url': u'https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-django/tp-un-raccourcisseur-d-url',
  'visits': 2},
 {'comment': u'NoComment',
  'creator': u'',
  'short': u'xeSkCWB',
  'url': u'https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-django/tp-un-raccourcisseur-d-urlfze',
  'visits': 0}]
```

To pass it to a request.session field, I want to convert it to JSON. Therefore I have `arrj = json.dumps(arr)`

However when I de-serialize it, I can not access the dictionaries:

```
arro = json.loads(arrj)
```

Here is the content of arro:

```
[{u'comment': u'NoComment',
  u'creator': u'',
  u'short': u'WQhBxVA',
  u'url': u'https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-django/tp-un-raccourcisseur-d-url',
  u'visits': 2},
 {u'comment': u'NoComment',
  u'creator': u'',
  u'short': u'xeSkCWB',
  u'url': u'https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-django/tp-un-raccourcisseur-d-urlfze',
  u'visits': 0}]
```

Because of the u (unicode tag?) a call like `arro[0].url` raises `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'url'`

Is there a way for me to get the `url` field of the deserialized array of dictionaries?

Comment: that's a dict. you access it by keys, like any dict: `dict[u'key']`

Comment: haha of course --' thank you very much this was stupid :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a JSON problem. Dictionaries do not expose their keys as attributes. Use indexing:

```
arro[0]['url']
```

Keys with ASCII-only characters are automatically decoded to match Unicode keys, so either `'url'` or `u'url'` will work.

Answer (score 1):

You do not access items inside dict as `dict.key` , you need to access using subscript - `dict[key]` . Example -

```
arro[0]['url']
```

This error has nothing to do with the `u` pre-pended to the strings .